# Rolled a 3 from a randomly choosing betwen 6 and 4 sided dice. What is the probability the dice was 4 sided

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I can't determine if this is simply a conditional probability with the probability of rolling a 3 from a 4 sided dice being 1/2*1/4, or if this may actually require a Bayesian approach.

Comment: Definitely Bayesian!

Comment: $\frac12\cdot\frac14$ is the probability of choosing the four-sided die and then rolling a $3$.  The question is the reverse: you randomly pick a die and roll a $3$.  What is the probability that it was the four-sided die you chose?  So, yeah, it needs Bayes' rule.

Comment: If you get any number Four or smaller, the chances of you used D4 are 3/5. If you get a Five or a Six, you must have used D6. For your specific problem, start by finding the total probability of getting a Three: (1/4)(1/2) + (1/6)(1/2) = 5/12.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly realized that you are asked the conditional probability of having picked the 4 sided die *given* that you rolled a $3$, but the $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{4}$ is not a conditional probability. Rather, that's the probability of rolling a 3 *and* picking the 4 sided dice.

That is, you computed $P(D4 \cap R3)$, but you want to compute $P(D4 | R3)$ where

$D4$ : event of picking $4$ sided die

$R3$ : event of rolling a $3$

And for that, indeed you should use the Bayesian rule.

I also would like to point out that your answer of $\frac{1}{8}$ should have pretty obviously been incorrect, for that would mean that there was a $\frac{7}{8}$ chance that you had picked the 6 sided die given a roll of 3, i.e. that the chance of having picked the latter die was *seven* times the chance of having picked the former?! Given that the two dice have a similar number of sides, the chance should be much closer to $\frac{1}{2}$ for wither one. So, getting $\frac{1}{8}$ should have set off the alarm bells right away.

In fact, given that the 4 sided die has fewer sides, the chance of having picked that one given a roll of 3 should be a little over $\frac{1}{2}$: think of the extreme situation where you have a 1 sided die whose only side is a 3, and a 1000 sided die only one of which is a 3. Now, if  yu roll a 3, which die is more likely to have been used? The 1 sided die of course, since it is more likely to come up with a 3 than the 1000 sidd die. Well, likewise, the 4 sides die is more likely to get a 3 than the 6 sided die, and therefore, getting a 3 means that you more likely used the 4 sided die than the 6 sided die. But given that the 4 sided die is not all that more likely to get a 3 than the 6 sided die, it follows that having rolled a 3, you are only slightly more likely to have used the 4 sided die than the 6 sided die, meaning that the answer should be a little over $\frac{1}{2}$

The moral is: always consider your answer and see if it makes intuitive sense!

Comment: Thank you. To solve this, we would need P(R3|D4), P(D4), and  P(R3). P(D4) = 1/2. P(R3) - I'm not 100% on this one. I think BruceET in the comment above got this at 5/12. So that leaves finding the probability of rolling a 3 given the dice is 4 sided. In this case, wouldn't that simply be 1/4? If so, the P(D4|R3) = (1/2*1/4)/(5/12) = 30%?

Comment: @meb33 Yes, $P(R3|D4)$ is just $\frac{1}{4}$. But $P(R3)=P(R3|D4)\cdot P(D4) + P(R3|D6) \cdot P(D6)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{12}=\frac{5}{24}$, rather than $\frac{5}{12}$ ... guess BruceT made a little typo. So, you get $P(D4|R3)=\frac{\frac{1}{8}}{\frac{5}{24}}=\frac{3}{5}$ ... and it makes sense that that would be more than $\frac{1}{2}$ given that the D4 has fewer sides than the D6 ... see my Answer